# Backbone Repeating Events

Tags: events, backbone.js, view, duplicates

I have just begun learning Backbone and have just noticed a bug in my code, but I'm not sure how to solve it.

Each time a button is clicked in the ControlView, it loads the view associated with that button click. Great! But, if you click a button (#button-1), click the adjacent button (#button-2) and then the first button again (#button-1) - we will now have two instances of that view, which of course leads to duplicated events. Which then means for each time I submit a form in that view, I get n + 2 HTTP requests.

I have adapted my code to create the views on first initialization, and these are then rendered each time they are needed. Is this the best way to go about it?

Many thanks!

```
        var ControlView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: $(".btn-group"),

    active: 'btn-primary',

    initialize: function()
    {
        _.bindAll(this, 'account', 'password');
        this.account();
    },

    events: {
        "click button.account"  : "account",
        "click button.password" : "password"
    },

    account: function()
    {
        this.reset();
        this.state("button.account");

        profile.fetch({
            success: function()
            {
                AccountView.render();
            }
        });
    },

    password: function()
    {
        this.reset();
        this.state("button.password");

        PasswordView.render();
    },

    state: function(element)
    {
        $(element).addClass(this.active);
    },

    reset: function()
    {
        $(this.el).find("button").removeClass(this.active);
    },

});

AccountView = new AccountView({model:profile});
PasswordView = new PasswordView({model:user});

ControlView = new ControlView;
```

Answer (score 3):

Backbone uses **el** element delegate to attach the events to the child elements. It does not bind events directly to the selectors. The problem is, that you are reusing the same element.

```
el: $(".btn-group")
```

Each time your view renders a new set of events is attached to **el**. But because the **el** is never removed from the dom, the event keep multiplying. When triggered all of the delegated events will fire.

Backbone events assume, that **el** element is going to rendered by the view itself each time. This way all the previously delegated events get destroyed when re-rendering the view.

Comment: Ah, right! So I should actually have an el element which is not in the DOM yet, this way it gets re-rendered each time, destroying the previously attached events?

Comment: Exactly. Or you can undelegate the events manually before each new rendering, but that is a very inconvenient approach.